# onKeyListner not called untill Done is pressed

Tags: android, keylistener

I've added the setOnKeyListener to an AutoCompleteTextView but when i press keys the onKey is not called . It is called only when I press Done... 
can anyone help?

```
    AutoCompleteTextView userInput = (AutoCompleteTextView) chooseContactView.findViewById(R.id.choose_contact);
    userInput.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String input = ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).getText().toString();

            readContactData(input);


            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a text-changed listener? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`addTextChangedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) as a listener for changes in the `TextView`.

Comment: Thanks! it worked... I thought I checked all the listeners :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use also TextWatcher e.g.:

```
    userInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```